# BlockSdk no modules object is callable

Tags: python

I think I did it the same way how document says. https://github.com/Block-Chen/blocksdk-python

```
import BlockSDK

client = BlockSDK("WQlSQN4yxlMi5Sv1F4GVgmJjD32OzmPz4lAlx2zI")
btcClient = client.createBitcoin()
blockchain = btcClient.getBlockChain()

print(blockchain)
```

However:

```
client = BlockSDK("WQlSQN4yxlMi5Sv1F4GVgmJjD32OzmPz4lAlx2zI")

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I don't know why. Please help me! Thanks

Comment: Maybe not.. There is BlockSDK class in BlockSDK folder. I think this is the problem and I cannot find appropriate answer

Comment: Modules are explained in the Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html, and classes too: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html